# force https on any subdomain with a wildcard certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

My app allow users to create a page using a subdomain, so I have hundreds of subdomains.

I bought a Wildcard certificate and it works fine when you type the complete URL:

```
https://foo.mydomain.com
https://bar.mydomain.com
https://foo.mydomain.com/controller/method/argument
https://bar.mydomain.com?id=234
```

However I doesn't work if you miss to type HTTPS://
In that case you will be redirected to the root domain (mydomain.com)

My intention is to force HTTPS while keeping the URL.

This is what I have in my htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That should work, what's the problem? As long as you are specifying `RewriteEngine on` before it. Line two is not needed, it's covered by the first line. The NE flag is not needed either.

Comment: The problem is that when someone types <foo.example.com> it is redirected to <https://example.com> when it should redirect to <https://foo.example.com>. Maybe it is not related to this. Thanks for your comment.